# WiX Burn failing to run on TeamCity build server

Tags: wix, teamcity, burn, wix3.8

I have an installer that uses Burn, and I have no problem building the installer on my (64-bit) dev machine. On our (64-bit) build server, I get this error:

*[Step 1/3] 2014-04-24 10:40:09,800 [2796] WARN  JetBrains.Container.Log4netDefaultLoggerInitializer - Unhandled exception in current domain: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\Heat.exe' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.*

From the *incorrect format* warning it is clear I have an x86/x64 clash going on, but where? All the projects in the solution with the installer are set to Any CPU and the build parameters in TeamCity are to build to x64. My installer project is set to x86 and I think this is the problem. I've tried setting the installer to x64, but then I get errors like this one:

*This 64BitComponent MyAppPool uses 32BitDirectory INSTALLLOCATION*

I think TeamCity is trying to run the x86 Burn.exe as an x64 (since that's how I've configured the build) hence the problem, but what's the solution? I need to build to x64, so setting the build to x86 isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

Since the underlying models for the Burn framework are written in C++ and compiled as x86 modules, you'll need to target your assemblies to x86 as well (not "Any CPU"). By default, if the first assembly loaded is running in x64 mode, then any downstream assembly loads that are x86 will likely fail, so to be safe, you should target them all to x86.

Comment: So is there no way to run Burn when compiling for x64?